# Why docker entry point script fails when in contrast it runs perfectly inside container manually?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a Ubuntu:20.04 image with my software being installed by dockerfile RUN commands. So the script i want to execute is build by Dockerfile RUN call to buildmyscripts.sh
This program installs perfectly and then if i run the container (with default entrypoint of /bin/sh or /bin/bash)
and execute manually: `/root/build/script.sh -i arg1 -m arg2` it works then.

However same doesn't work with ENTRYPOINT set to the /root/build/script.sh followed by CMD set to the arguments. I get following error on running the image

`Error: cannot load shared library xyz.so`

Xyz.so is a common shared library installed by RUN anyway before.

Please assist thanks
Note: i run as USER root because i have self hosted runner on a hardened Server so security not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently we need to source the script for environment variables by prepending to the entrypoint/cmd variable in dockerfile. Since the source was through another script it wasnt working alone with ENV variable